# Google Chart is not drawn on UpdatePanel's ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock call

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, registerclientscriptblock

I'm triggering a client side script based on events in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel.  It works when the page is actually refreshed, but not at all when the same code is triggered by one of the UpdatePanel's events.  The google chart control seems to require window.onload.   Is there any work around?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">    
<ContentTemplate >
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="False" Interval="3000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="True">
        <asp:Label ID="QuestionText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ResponseList" runat="server">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitResponse" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="SubmitResponse_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="False">
        <div>
            Thank you for taking this poll...                
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Visible="False">
        <div id="chart_div">
            Google Chart showing Survey Results should appear here.
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetPoll();
        string drawGoogleChartScript = GetDrawGoogleChartsScript();

        if (!UserHasResponded(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name))            
        {               
            QuestionText.Text = Poll.Question;
            ResponseList.DataSource = Poll.PossibleResponses;
            ResponseList.DataBind();
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            HiddenPollId.Value = Poll.PollId;
        }
        else if(_submitButtonClicked && !_thankYouMessageHasBeenDisplayed )
        { 
            //Return and wait for the Timer event to fire
            return;
        }
        else if(!_submitButtonClicked && _thankYouMessageHasBeenDisplayed )
        {
            //The Timer event has fired
            _thankYouMessageHasBeenDisplayed = false;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "DrawChart1", GetDrawGoogleChartsScript(), false);
        }
        else
        {
            //The user has already taken the poll - visible on every visit after they take it.
            if (Panel1.Visible == true)
            {
                Panel1.Visible = false;
            }
            if (Panel3.Visible == false)
            {
                Panel3.Visible = true;
            }

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.Page.GetType(), "DrawChart2", GetDrawGoogleChartsScript(), false);                               
        }
    }


protected void SubmitResponse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _submitButtonClicked = true;
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
        {
            using( SPWeb web = site.RootWeb ) 
            {
                SPList responseList = web.Lists[ResponseListName];                    
                SPListItem item = responseList.AddItem();

                item["Response"] = ResponseList.SelectedItem.Text;
                item["PollId"] = HiddenPollId.Value;
                item["UserId"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;

                item.Update();
            }
        }

        //Hide the Question
        Panel1.Visible = false;

        //Show "Thank you for taking the poll message"
        Panel2.Visible = true;

        //Start the Timer - (countdown to swith over to the results)
        Timer1.Enabled = true;

    }       



    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _submitButtonClicked = false;
        _thankYouMessageHasBeenDisplayed = true;

        //Hide the "Thank you for taking the poll" message
        Panel2.Visible = false;

        //Show panel with the 'char_div' where the chart will be injected
        Panel3.Visible = true;

        //Stop the timer
        Timer1.Enabled = false;

    }
```

GetDrawGoogleChartsScript() Returns the following in a string:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

       function drawChart(){
         data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         data.addColumn('string', 'Agreement');
         data.addColumn('number', 'choice');
         data.addRows([['Strongly Disagree', 3],['Disagree', 1],['Neutral', 1],['Agree', 1],['Strongly Agree', 2]])
         var options = { 'title': 'My manager has taken positive steps to increase engagement since the Q12 Survey.', 'width': 400, 'height': 300 };
         var chart = new                  google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

I'm using an ASP.NET UpdatePanel to present a survey question + a submit button, then a "Thanks for taking the survey" message, and finally present the results of the survey in a google chart.

The chart works when the page is refreshed, but I cannot get it to work using the Async events.

I'm posting a lot of code but the essential problem is that when we re-enter Page_PreRender after the Timer_Tick event fires, we execute the line: 
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "DrawChart1", GetDrawGoogleChartsScript(), false);

(Which is the same as the code that is executed when we reload the page after completing the survey.)  But nothing happens!  The script is not loaded at all.

The parameters for the bar chart are actually computed dynamically, so I have to use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to add it to the page.

The javascript does not even make it into the page source in the case of the Async event, even though I can watch the line that calls ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock get executed.

After 4 days of banging my head against this, I'm very "challenged" with this, so any help you can provide will be *greatly* appreciated.

Cheers,

Trey Carroll

Comment: How did you declare `_submitButtonClicked` and `_thankYouMessageHasBeenDisplayed`?  Are they static?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue has to do with the fact that you were either set controls visiblity in the codebehind or on the clientside.  You cannot do both and have it work correctly.  Are you aware of this?  I have had many headaches due to this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The Google script doesn't depend on `window.onload`; I suspect what's happening is this:

1. Timer event fires, and script block gets rendered to the client
2. Client script loads Google visualization library, fires `drawChart` callback --> nothing happens, because `Panel3` is not yet visible
3. Timer fires again, and now `Panel3` is made visible.  The client script runs again, but this time `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)` doesn't trigger the callback, because the Google script has already been loaded

To rectify this, I suggest a simple test.  Check for whether the Google API is already loaded; if it's not, invoke the `drawChart` function manually:

```
if (typeof google.visualization == 'undefined') {
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
}
else {
    drawChart();
}
```

This should cause the chart to render correctly.